# Populate summary "table" column based on details "table"

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I've tried looking up how this might be done, but it's a bit beyond my excel-fu, unfortunately (I could do it in SQL in a snap!).

Basically, in one worksheet, I have the following details "table" (I've included the column and row labels):

```
      A     B       C     D
 1  owner  name  line #  run?
 2  A      A1        10  Y
 3  A      A1        20  N
 4  A      A2         2  Y
 5  A      A2        14  Y
 6  A      A3        34  N
 7  B      B1        26  Y
 8  B      B1        59  Y
 9  B      B1       193  Y
10  B      B1       194  Y
11  B      B2        27  N
12  B      B2        51  N
```

and I have the following summary "table" on a different worksheet

```
    A     B       C
 1 owner  name  status
 2 A      A1
 3 A      A2
 4 A      A3
 5 B      B1
 5 B      B2
```

I need to populate the `status` column in the summary "table" based on the `run?` column in the details "table", linked on the owner and name columns.

Here are the results I'm expecting to get, along with why:

```
     A     B            C                                       D
 1 owner  name  expected status  reason
 2 A      A1    Partial          There are Y and N values for owner=A and name=A1 in the details table
 3 A      A2    Complete         There are only Y values for the owner=A and name=A2 in the details table
 4 A      A3    Not Started      There are only N values for the owner=A and name=A3 in the details table
 5 B      B1    Complete         There are only Y values for the owner=B and name=B1 in the details table
 5 B      B2    Not Started      There are only N values for the owner=B and name=B2 in the details table
```

I know I'll probably need countifs to work out if there are Y's and N's present, plus an IF to turn the output into the words, it's the getting to the point where I can count the Y's and N's present for each owner+name that I'm struggling with.

I have googled how I might find out if there were Y's and/or N's present for a given owner and name, and have come across [this link which involves `MATCH` and `INDEX`](https://exceljet.net/formula/lookup-entire-column) but for the life of me, I can't get it working - I get an output of `#N/A`, using the following formula to get the first status:

```
=INDEX(A2:D12,0,MATCH(c2,'<Detail worksheet>'!A2:D12,0))
```

Am I on the right lines or is there a better way of doing this? (I could always manually specify the range of rows to look down in the details "table" for each summary "table" row, but I'd like to avoid that if possible!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split the formula into two parts, which should get you most of the way there. If you have an uncertain length of data, then be careful with how many rows you examine, my answer only goes to row 13.

`Summary Sheet` with columns added to split formula

[image]

```
Sheet 1
```

[image: Sheet1]

The formula for the Y column in the above picture is:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$E$3:$E$13,Sheet2!$D$2,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$13,Sheet2!$B3,Sheet1!$C$3:$C$13,Sheet2!$C3)
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I've managed to combine it into one column `=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$E$3:$E$13,"Y",Sheet1!$B$3:$B$13,Sheet2!$B3,Sheet1!$C$3:$C$13,Sheet2!$C3)>0, 1, 0) + IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$E$3:$E$13,"N",Sheet1!$B$3:$B$13,Sheet2!$B3,Sheet1!$C$3:$C$13,Sheet2!$C3)>0, 2, 0)`, and all I need to do is put some `if`s around it to rename it to the correct status name. Now, if only my version of excel had the `switch` function!